# Rouché–Capelli theorem for matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to solve matrix equations over the finite field $GF(2)$ in Maple. First of all, I need to find out if the matrix equation has a solution. And I have a question. Please help me.

Is the Rouché–Capelli theorem for matrix equations true? That is, for equations
$$
AX=B
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are given matrices and $X$ is the unknown matrix.

So, is it true that this system has a solution if and only if
$$
\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(A|B)?
$$

As I see, over the field $GF(2)$ or over the field $\mathbb{R}$ - it does not matter.

Comment: Let us consider first the case of a one column matrix $X$, resp. $B$. (Then arrange the situation using block matrix computations...)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^{(j)}, b^{(j)}$ denote the $j$th columns of $X$ and $B$ respectively. Note that stating $AX = B$ is equivalent to stating that $Ax^{(j)} = b^{(j)}$ for every $j$. Since each of these problems are independent (i.e. solving one puts no particular constraints on any other), you really just need to ask when any arbitrary one is solvable.

Recall that solving $Ax^{(j)} = b^{(j)}$ is essentially just representing $b^{(j)}$ as a linear combination of the columns of $A$, so it follows that it is solvable if and only if $$\mathrm{rank}(A | b^{(j)}) = \mathrm{rank}(A).$$
If every $b^{(j)}$ is linearly dependent on the columns of $A$, then so is the set of them. From this you can infer that $\mathrm{rank}(A |B) = \mathrm{rank}(A)$. Finally, all of these inferences can be reversed, so $\mathrm{rank}(A |B) = \mathrm{rank}(A)$ implies that  a solution exists.